# How do I best dump a Psych::Nodes::Document back to a YAML string?

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

This does what I want, but going via `to_ruby` seems unnecessary:

```
doc = Psych.parse("foo: 123")
doc.to_ruby.to_yaml
# => "---\nfoo: 123\n"
```

When I try to do this, I get an error:

```
DEV 16:49:08 >> Psych.parse("foo: 123").to_yaml
RuntimeError: expected STREAM-START
from /opt/…/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/visitors/emitter.rb:42:in `start_mapping'
```

I get the impression that the input needs to be a stream of some sort, but I don't quite get what incantation I need. Any ideas?

(The problem I'm trying to solve here, by the way (in case you know of a better way) is to fix some YAML that can't be deserialised into Ruby, because it references classes that don't exist. The YAML is quite complex, so I don't want to just search-and-replace in the YAML string. My thinking was that I could use `Psych.parse` to get a syntax tree, modify that tree, then dump it back into a YAML string.)

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the incantation after finding the higher-level docs at https://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.3.0_preview1/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Nodes.html, though please let me know if there's a better way:

```
doc = Psych.parse("foo: 123")
stream = Psych::Nodes::Stream.new
stream.children << doc
stream.to_yaml
# => "foo: 123\n"
```